# Building Assimp with CMake

Tags: cmake, assimp

I want to use the assimp library (http://assimp.sourceforge.net/) in my Qt Application (Compiler: MSVC2013).

My problem is that I can't figure out how to build the library. Here is what I have tried.

1. I downloaded assimp-3.1.1.zip and CMake.
2. Ran CMake-gui
3. Chose in "Where is the source code" the unpacked folder of assimp-3.1.1.zip.
4. In "Where to build the binaries" I chose a new folder that i made called "cmake binary/3.1.1".
5. I selected "Configure" and chose Visual Studio 12 2013 Win64 and "Use Default native Compilers".
6. I unchecked "BUILD_SHARED_LIBS" and checked "BUILD_STATIC_LIB" and "ENABLE_BOOST_WORKAROUND"
7. I hit "Generate".

Once I opened the generated "Assimp.sln" with Visual Studio (I am not sure if its the right way, because i want to use it with Qt afterwards) and built "ALL_BUILD" by rightclick->Build. This one works but now comes the problem: If I build "INSTALL" i get the following error:

```
Error   20  error MSB3073: The command "setlocal
C:\Data-NoBackup\CMake\bin\cmake.exe -DBUILD_TYPE=Debug -P cmake_install.cmake
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
:cmEnd
endlocal & call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto :cmDone
:cmErrorLevel
exit /b %1
:cmDone
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd
:VCEnd" exited with code 1. C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets  132 5   INSTALL"
```

After Googling this error and found that I have to run my programms as an Administrator (according to https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/02d24b1e-65ff-4177-bdf2-0d1e0fb8cdf6/error-msb3073-and-my-build-exited-with-code-1).

But this doesnt help me. I still get this error. I hope you are able to help me here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using it without installation? Is it working? Was configure and building without errors?

Answer (score 1):

I was also having this issue, and found it was related to this issue here:

https://github.com/assimp/assimp/issues/500

It seems there's an issue with the `cmake_install.cmake` file not finding debug symbols.

I found that by disabling `ASSIMP_INSTALL_PDB` (via `-DASSIMP_INSTALL_PDB=FALSE`) the build worked as intended.